# FluentValidation Validate Method throwing an excepion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm having some issues the using FluentValidation library.

I have a very small Model
   `

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(PersonValidator))]
 public class PersonModel
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Nullable<short> Type { get; set; }
}
```

`

Have a validator class

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonModel>
{   
    public PersonValidator()
    {

        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
        .Length(1, 5)
            .WithLocalizedMessage(() => BaseValidationResource.LengthValidationMessage, 1, 5);


    }
}
```

And I have a controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var model = new PersonModel();
        model.Name = "John Doe";

        var validator = new PersonValidator();
        var results = validator.Validate(model);
        var error = GetModelErrors();

        return View(model);
    }
```

So far so good, the issue is that when the progam is executing and it gets to the line with ; `var results = validator.Validate(model);` it throws a SystemFormatException.

[image]

Instead of throwing an exception, shouldn't the validate method just return an object containing a boolean field which indicates if the model is valid and a list of errors.

PS : I  know that this particular validation can also be done using DataAnnotations but i want to use Fluentvalidation because its more flexible.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is `BaseValidationResource.LengthValidationMessage`

Comment: Oh there I'm just pointing to an error message on my resources file, because of localization

Comment: Could you post the code for it?

Comment: @RIc sorry for late reply. I didn't even think about the resource file, but after you asked to see it, i went and commented out the line for displaying the error message, and magically the method stopped bombing out. After inspecting the file closely i found the root of the issue. 

Thanks a lot for your help, i have spent more than a day on it and i would never get to the solution without your clinical observation.

Comment: Maybe have been a string formatting issue, at a guess without seeing it! Glad it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

As @RIc pointed out was a string formatting issue on my Resource file.

On my validor i had this line

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Name)
        .Length(1, 5)
            .WithLocalizedMessage(() => BaseValidationResource.LengthValidationMessage, 1, 5);
```

Which pointed to the resource file and passed 2 parameters. But on my resource file i was expecting 3 parameters (property name, min value, max value).

However i was using the wrong annotation. Below are the before and after version of the the resource file.

[image]